# DSN creation through vb6 code for mysql odbc driver 3.51 not working in windows 64 bit

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc, dsn

Can anybody help me, the following code vb6 is working fine in windows 7 32 bit but not working in windows 10 32 or windows 10 64 bit.

My vb6 code for dsn creation for mysql database odbc driver 3.51 is as under :-

```
Private Declare Function SQLConfigDataSource Lib "ODBCCP32.DLL" (ByVal hwndParent As Integer, ByVal fRequest As Integer, 
                                                             ByVal lpszDriver As String, ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Integer

Dim Attr as string

 Attr = "SERVER=localhost" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "DSN=ABC" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "DESCRIPTION=DSN For ABC" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "DATABASE=mysqltestdb" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "User=root" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "Password=abctest" & Chr(0)
        Attr = Attr & "option=2" & Chr(0)
        iReturn = SQLConfigDataSource(0, 1, "MySql ODBC 3.51 Driver", Attr)
```

Comment: You listed several windows variants in the "not working" section - is that written correctly? Because you list a 32 bit version there while stating that this is a 64 bit problem. (Note that you can edit the text of your question if needed).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 64-bit systems, 32 bit versions of DLLs are located in the **"C:\Windows\SysWOW64"** folder. By default, `SQLConfigDataSource` is loading from the **"C:\Windows\System32"** folder which contains 64-bit DLLs, which causes the function to error out.

I know this folder naming seems backwards, but it really is how it's designed and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/) explains why that's the case.

Declare the function as follows and then try:

```
Private Declare Function SQLConfigDataSource _ 
Lib "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ODBCCP32.DLL" (ByVal hwndParent As Integer, _ 
                                        ByVal fRequest As Integer, _ 
                                        ByVal lpszDriver As String, _ 
                                        ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Integer
```

Comment: I'm surprised to learn there is a DLL named "ODBCCP32.DLL" in the 64 bit folder (system32) - but I checked on my PC and there it is.

Comment: Hardcoding the absolute path may work but also makes me uncomfortable. Normally this isn't necessary. I think that the VB6 runtime, being 32 bit, should be trying to first load 32 bit DLLs from SysWow64. I'm surprised that it would find a 64 bit DLL first.